# powerBI DAX for counting different statuses per day

Tags: powerbi, dax

So I have a table with detailed information of jira tickets.

```
Summary| Description| status| created<br>
xady     | adfafgaf   | Failed  | 1.2.2020
1dy     | adfafgaf   | Expected| 1.2.2020
xafy     | adfafgaf   | Closed  | 2.2.2020
x13y     | adfafgaf   | Closed  | 3.2.2020
```

No I want to have a diagram which shows me for everyday of the months the count grouped by status. The problem is that I need this **aggregated**.
So for the example above I want a bar chart which displays me this

```
1.2. :  1 Failed / 1 Expected
2.2. :  1 Failed / 1 Expected / 1 Closed
3.2. :  1 Failed / 1 Expected / 2 Closed
```

How can I achieve this in powerBI ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have the status per day knowing how many have been created, closed, failed etc. this from start of first day?

Comment: yes exactly  @aldert

Answer (score 0):

Create this below measure-

```
concanated_status = 

VAR failed_count = 
COUNTAX(
    FILTER(
        ALL(concanate_table),
        concanate_table[created] <= MIN(concanate_table[created])
            && concanate_table[status] = "Failed"
    ),
    concanate_table[status]
)

VAR Expected_count = 
COUNTAX(
    FILTER(
        ALL(concanate_table),
        concanate_table[created] <= MIN(concanate_table[created])
            && concanate_table[status] = "Expected"
    ),
    concanate_table[status]
)

VAR Closed_count = 
COUNTAX(
    FILTER(
        ALL(concanate_table),
        concanate_table[created] <= MIN(concanate_table[created])
            && concanate_table[status] = "Closed"
    ),
    concanate_table[status]
)


RETURN 
IF(
    failed_count = BLANK(), 
    BLANK(), 
    failed_count &" Failed"
)
&
IF(
    Expected_count = BLANK(), 
    BLANK(), 
    " / " & Expected_count &" Expected"
)
&
IF(
    Closed_count = BLANK(), 
    BLANK(), 
    " / " & Closed_count &" Closed"
)
```

Now add Date and Measure to the **Table Visual**. You can adjust the **Date** value as per your requirement as you shown Date as - "01.02"

[image]